# Mapping a command with another command in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

Just trying to remap the command to open bufferexplorer (\be) with the shorter version (\b). 
My try is:

```
map <leader>b <ESC><leader>be<CR>
```

Needless to say, this does not work. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The original command itself is likely just a mapping to a command line mode command. I looked up the `\be` in BufExplorer's help and it says an alternative way of invoking would be `:BufExplorer`. So try the following:

```
noremap <silent> <leader>b :BufExplorer<CR>
```

Or maybe `nmap` instead of `map` depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks @AUAnonymous. Just for completeness, it is required to add <CR> at the end of your suggested mapping.

Comment: In this case you should use `noremap`. In original question `nore` cannot be used, but here you should use only it: you can't say that user7124 has not remapped `:` in normal mode (two mappings exchanging `:` and `;` are not uncommon).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `<CR>` there? Your mapping will invoke bufexplorer and immediately exit it, choosing buffer under cursor (it is current buffer, is not it?) (I may be mistaking as I used bufexplorer only for a few hours). Correct one is

```
map <leader>b <C-\><C-n><leader>be
```

I also suggest replacing `<Esc>` with `<C-\><C-n>` which unconditionally exits to normal mode without beeping, it may be used for throwing away register and count too.

Note that `mapleader` variable must be at the same state as it were when bufexplorer defined its `<leader>be` mapping.

Answer (score -1):

Since default leader symbol is `\` you can just

```
map <leader>b <ESC>\be<CR>
```

but if you care for actual leader symbol value, try something like

```
:execute 'map <leader>b <ESC>' . (exists('mapleader') ? mapleader : '\') . 'be<CR>'
```

where construction `(exists('mapleader') ? mapleader : '\')` substitutes appropriate leader symbol (see `:help mapleader`).

Note: if you change `mapleader` value *after* this mapping command, the mapping will beсome useless

Comment: `<leader>` works in rhs just as good as it does in lhs. And «if you change mapleader value after this mapping command, the mapping will beсome useless» is false: as clearly stated in help, when mapleader changes mappings are not redefined. So mapping will become useless only if mapleader is changed *between* running bufexplorer and user mapping commands.